# extract numbers from a string if they meet a specific condition

Tags: php, string

In the following string there are some numbers followed by two letters "ST". How can I extract all of those numbers?

```
$str = '104 ST Lorem 104 ipsum (dolor) sit ST, 2000 ST adipiscing 2 2 ST elit.'
```

In the above string there is 104 ST, 2000 ST and 2 ST.

Comment:  http://regular-expressions.info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `preg_match_all` here with the pattern `(\d+) ST\b`:

```php
$str = "104 ST Lorem 104 ipsum (dolor) sit ST, 2000 ST adipiscing 2 2 ST elit.";
preg_match_all("/(\d+) ST\b/", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 104
    [1] => 2000
    [2] => 2
)
```